# UIScrollview 'skips' page on lazy loading

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm implementing a sort of 'lazy loading' algorithm in a `UIScrollView`. I need to detect if a page is 'fully' displayed, like if there is only one page visible. So I'm using this code:

```
    -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)myScrollView {


float currentPage = ((float)myScrollView.contentOffset.x/ (self.view.frame.size.width));
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", currentPage]);


    if(currentPage >= [[NSNumber numberWithInt:_currentIndex + 1]floatValue])
    {
        _currentIndex = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentPage]intValue];
        NSLog(@"----");
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _currentIndex]);
        [self moveFirstToLast];

    }
    else if (currentPage <= [[NSNumber numberWithInt:_currentIndex - 1]floatValue])
    {
        _currentIndex = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentPage]intValue];
        NSLog(@"----");
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _currentIndex]);
        [self moveLastToFirst];
    }
```

The first part of the code is alright. The `UIScrollview` detects correctly when a page is 'fully visible' and performs the `[self moveFirstToLast]` function. This happens when the user does a rightscroll gesture.

BUT, when i scroll left, and fast, sometimes the algorithm skips a step! So the `[self moveLastToFirst]` isn't always performed correctly on time. I don't know how this comes? Anyone? Is there maybe a better way to detect whether a page is fully displayed?

I already tried the `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;` function, but same problem, when scrolling to fast, this method isn't called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not my cup of thee.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to implement reuse of views inside the scroll view when user is scrolling, you should follow next rules:

1. Always previous, current and next pages are loaded (except cases when you have current page as first or last one).
2. Dequeue and reorder of non-visible page should happen when you meet a half of next page in direction you are scrolling. E.g. for left scrolling

   ```
   myScrollView.contentOffset.x <= (0.5f + (_currentIndex - 1)) * myScrollView.bounds.size.width;
   ```

**UPD 1**

3 .  When reusing - you should just move the non visible page instead of removing/adding it as a subview onto scrollView.

**UPD 2**: You can also try using UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling and cells with size of whole page instead of implementing your own reuse mechanism.

Comment: This works, but when I dequeue and reorder in the middle of the scrolling, there is some kind of... I don't know how to say in english.. The animation isn't fluent anymore. So my thought was: Lets dequeue and reorder when the previous (or the next page) is fully shown.